# How to use gradle file tree in groovyTestcase

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I am migrating a project from ant to gradle. I want to write a simple test case using GrooveTest framework.
I am trying to use Gradle project.fileTree interface in GroovyTestCase, how ever it is not able to resolve it. The same piece of code works in "test" task in build.gradle.

Here is my simple test case look like.

```
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.file.FileTree
class  InstallScriptTest extends GroovyTestCase {

        void testCounnt(){
            def tree = project.fileTree("${project.projectDir}"){
                include '**/install*.sh'
            }

        }

}
```

I get following error when I run the gradle build.
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: project for class: InstallScriptTest

I have added the gradleAPI dependency in build.gradle file as below.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:2.4.3'   
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile gradleApi()
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test here? Also remember that test cases are completely different to the `Test` tasks in Gradle. `Test` tasks have implicit access to the Gradle project. Test cases have no inherent knowledge of Gradle.

Comment: I just want to leverage the features of gradle filetree interface in groovy test class. Just to check the number of files with install.sh and assert based on the count. Even though I have mentioned gradleAPI dependency the ggroovy not able resolve it. I can use any java or groovy file operations here but I just want ttry using filetree as gradle api too are written in groovy.

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that `gradleApi()` will include anything *but* the API, i.e. the interface classes. So even if you could get it to run, it might break in future. If you really wanted to do this, though, you might be able to get it to work via [`ProjectBuilder`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testfixtures/ProjectBuilder.html). I don't know though.